# Find out spender's that contributed to top 90% of total Spent

Tags: r, percentile

I have a dataframe in R with 2 columns - Names and Amount Spent. I want to find out the list of spenders that constituted the top 90% of total spent.

Short Example of my dataframe (in reality it has thousands of rows) -

```
DF <- data.frame(Names = letters[1:13], 
     Total_Spent = c(129777.73,1265.27,124906.61,12493.39,130.68,121709.55,12476.43,                                                        120235.74,120053.71,119582.76,113732.94,112417.77,1000.71))
```

My question comes from the need to filter out a lot of noise from data and remove spenders who do not constitute much. 90% is just a hypothetical number and I want to experiment and see the right number of spenders to remove. For example, if I see that 80% of spenders are only spending 10% of total spent amount, I will be happy to take only the other 20% for my analysis.

Any help or ideas on how to go about this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to order the data in descending order and select the rows until 90% is reached.

```
perc <- 0.9
DF <- DF[order(DF$Total_Spent, decreasing = TRUE),]
DF1 <- DF[cumsum(DF$Total_Spent) <= sum(DF$Total_Spent) * perc, ]
DF1

#   Names Total_Spent
#1      a    129777.7
#3      c    124906.6
#6      f    121709.6
#8      h    120235.7
#9      i    120053.7
#10     j    119582.8
#11     k    113732.9
```

You could change the `perc` value according to your choice.

Comment: Worked very well. I changed the format of the code to match it with dplyr as I am used to it but the logic is same. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work?

```
DF <- data.frame(Names = letters[1:13], Total_Spent = c(129777.73,1265.27,124906.61,12493.39,130.68,121709.55,12476.43, 120235.74,120053.71,119582.76,113732.94,112417.77,1000.71))

x<-quantile(DF[,2], 0.9)

DF_90<-which(DF[,2]>=x)
DF[,1][DF_90]
```

result:

```
[1] a c
```